# how to apply a function type with generic to a function

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type AllRoutes = {
  Home: undefined
  Page: { id: string }
}

type NavFunction<RouteName extends keyof AllRoutes> = (
  ...args: AllRoutes[RouteName] extends undefined
    ? [RouteName]
    : [RouteName, AllRoutes[RouteName]]
) => void
```

If I put this type directly on a function like this is works as expected:

```
export function navigate<RouteName extends keyof AllRoutes>(
  ...args: AllRoutes[RouteName] extends undefined
    ? [RouteName]
    : [RouteName, AllRoutes[RouteName]]
) {
  ...
}

navigate('Home') // works!
navigate('Page', {id: 1}) // works!
navigate('Page') // Expected 2 args
```

The issue I'm running into is that I would like to apply this type to multiple functions (each for a different platform). I can't seem to figure how how to apply the first type to a function and have it work like the "direct" example I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper type for the `args` portion. Maybe also create a type for `keyof AllRoutes`?:

```
type RouteNames = keyof AllRoutes;
type GetArgs<RouteName extends RouteNames> = AllRoutes[RouteName] extends undefined
    ? [RouteName]
    : [RouteName, AllRoutes[RouteName]];

export function navigate<RouteName extends RouteNames>(
  ...args: GetArgs<RouteName>
) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: great! I needed to make the following edit, but it seems to work:

`GetArgs<RouteName>` -> `GetArgs <RouteName extends RouteNames>`

Answer (score 2):

First, note that `NavFunction` type, while similar to `navigate`'s function type, *is in fact not the same*. It should instead have the generic part attached to the function, not to the type name, like so:

```
// Note the generic part is now attached to the start of the function
// signature, rather than as a part of the NavFunction type name.
type NavFunction = <RouteName extends keyof AllRoutes>(
  ...args: AllRoutes[RouteName] extends undefined
    ? [RouteName]
    : [RouteName, AllRoutes[RouteName]]
) => void
```

The difference being that in the original, `NavFunction` requires you to specify which argument to expect *up front*, whereas in the revised version, it will be inferred when the function is used.

With that, you can use a *function expression* instead of a *function declaration* to attach the type:

```
const navigate: NavFunction = function(...args) {
  // ...
}

navigate('Home') // works!
navigate('Page', {id: "1"}) // works!
navigate('Page') // Expected 2 args
```

But be aware that by doing it in this manner, the `navigate` function will no longer be hoisted. :(

Answer (score 2):

*This is not a direct answer but a proposition to change the problem.*

The expected usage of such functions is nice but requires a type not easy to maintain. What about using a whole object parameter with a discriminated union type?

```js
// Routes discriminated by name
type HomeRoute   = { name: 'Home' };
type PageRoute   = { name: 'Page'; id: number };
type SearchRoute = { name: 'Search'; text: string; limit?: number };

type Route = HomeRoute | PageRoute | SearchRoute;

function navigateV1(route: Route): void { /*...*/ }

navigateV1({ name: 'Home' })
navigateV1({ name: 'Page', id: 1 })
navigateV1({ name: 'Page' }) // Got expected error "Property 'id' is missing..."
navigateV1({ name: 'Search', text: 'A*' })
```

The usage is just a bit more verbose but also gives more detailed error.

--

By the way, with the above discriminated union type, to stick to the required usage, we need also complex utility types:

```js
// V2 (more complex to maintain) : arguments as deconstructed object
type RouteName = Route['name']; // "Home" | "Page" | "Search"

type RouteArgs<TRouteName extends RouteName,
               TRoute = Extract<Route, { name: TRouteName }>,
               TRest  = Omit<TRoute, 'name'>> =
  {} extends TRest
  ? [TRouteName]
  : [TRouteName, TRest];

type TestHomeRouteArgs   = RouteArgs<'Home'>;   // ["Home"]
type TestPageRouteArgs   = RouteArgs<'Page'>;   // ["Page", Pick<PageRoute, "id">]
type TestSearchRouteArgs = RouteArgs<'Search'>; // ["Search", Pick<PageRoute, "text" | "limit">]

function navigateV2<TRouteName extends RouteName>(...args: RouteArgs<TRouteName>): void { /*...*/ }

navigateV2('Home')
navigateV2('Page', { id: 1 })
navigateV2('Page') // Got expected error but less precise: "Expected 2 arguments but got 1"
navigateV2('Search', { text: 'A*' })

// ----
// V3 : even more complex but output types more readable
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer Tbis ? { [K in keyof Tbis]: Tbis[K] } : never;

type PrettyRouteArgs<TRouteName extends RouteName,
               TRoute = Extract<Route, { name: TRouteName }>,
               TRest  = Omit<TRoute, 'name'>> =
  {} extends TRest
  ? [TRouteName]
  : [TRouteName, Prettify<TRest>];

type TestPrettyHomeRouteArgs   = PrettyRouteArgs<'Home'>;   // ["Home"]
type TestPrettyPageRouteArgs   = PrettyRouteArgs<'Page'>;   // ["Page", { id: number; }]
type TestPrettySearchRouteArgs = PrettyRouteArgs<'Search'>; // ["Search", { text: string; limit?: number | undefined; }]

function navigateV3<TRouteName extends RouteName>(...args: PrettyRouteArgs<TRouteName>): void { /*...*/ }

navigateV3('Home')
navigateV3('Page', { id: 1 })
navigateV3('Page') // Got same expected error
navigateV3('Search', { text: 'A*' })
```