# TypeScript utility type over a discriminated union type

Tags: typescript

Given a discriminated union type like this:

```js
type HomeRoute   = { name: 'Home' };
type PageRoute   = { name: 'Page'; id: number };
type SearchRoute = { name: 'Search'; text: string; limit?: number };

type Route = HomeRoute | PageRoute | SearchRoute;
```

I would like an utility type that takes the union type and its the discriminant (here the type of the name member: `"Home" | "Page" | "Search"`) and returns the matching case:

```js
type Discriminate<TUnion, TDiscriminant> = ???

type TestHome = Discriminate<Route, 'Home'>; // Expecting "HomeRoute" (structure)
type TestPage = Discriminate<Route, 'Page'>; // Expecting "PageRoute" (structure)
```

Comment: Interesting, but what is motivation. Dicriminant should be treated as implementation detail

Comment: @MaciejSikora: I needed some tips to give this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60111896/8634147). `Extract` utility type was enough but both yours and @Titian generic answers are pretty interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most verbose solution would be:

```
type Discriminate<TUnion, TDiscriminant> = 
  TUnion extends {name: TDiscriminant} ? TUnion : never

type HomeMember = Discriminate<Route, 'Home'>;
type PageMember = Discriminate<Route, 'Page'>;
```

We can use also existing utility type Extract which will do conditional type for use:

```
type Discriminate<TUnion, TDiscriminant> = Extract<TUnion, {name: TDiscriminant}>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Extract` predefined conditional type:

```
type HomeRoute   = { name: 'Home' };
type PageRoute   = { name: 'Page'; id: number };
type SearchRoute = { name: 'Search'; text: string; limit?: number };

type Route = HomeRoute | PageRoute | SearchRoute;

type TestHome = Extract<Route, { name: 'Home' }>; 
type TestPage = Extract<Route, { name: 'Page' }>;
```

You can also create a generic version of `Discriminate` but not sure if it is worth it as you would need the field as well:

```
type Discriminate<TUnion, TField extends PropertyKey, TDiscriminant> = Extract<TUnion, Record<TField, TDiscriminant>>

type TestHome = Discriminate<Route, 'name', 'Home'>; // Expecting "HomeRoute" (structure)
type TestPage = Discriminate<Route, 'name', 'Page'>; // Expecting "PageRoute" (structure)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=90&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gWwgJTgV2NKUC8UDeUAdgIZIBcUA5PElVAL4DcAUKJFAAokDmK6mbLgLEyESlW58qTKAEsAJpSJoEAIwgAnRq3bQAyhBKaAxgAtUGaHkKkK1Q8fMyomAB7BKAZ2Ca5RHlkAGzkEOWAAfmVVDW1mFjZwaEtBPFp+KygAHy5eDMEcx1MLAQhWRI4AETkvEz8w0kwAHgAVAFUiOTgiABooFoAxOQgghSgIDwgiBS8uTThITVAAaQgQPpbq2vr-EiJgAD5hAFEPTRITYFaOrt6oZAgTOE0FVqGRhQ2tutDd-YODgk9P0ID50sJvjtGhAmikIH0qHYIFQEekqAdZAB6TFQU6QS7+HhQABE6ThxKgAAofJo0Jc0JoIABKCrQFqg4BSaxQSG-aGw0oIpEo6hc9FYnF4x7AQkkrnkqk0unABnMoA)

Comment: Simplified for his case and need would be `type Discriminate<TUnion, TDiscriminant> = Extract<TUnion, Record<'name', TDiscriminant>>`