# Get a subset of a discriminated union based on a subset of the discriminator

Tags: typescript

Typescript question:

Given a discriminated union type

```
interface A {
    discriminator: "A";
    data: string;
}

interface B {
    discriminator: "B";
    data: string;
}

interface C {
    discriminator: "C";
    num: number;
}

type U = A | B | C;
type Discriminator = U["discriminator"];

type AorB = SubsetOfU<"A"|"B">;

const f = (d:AorB) => d.data; // Should work
```

How do I write `SubsetOfU` to extract a subset of the union type?

I'm not after solving the specific case here, of course (would be just `A|B`), but a more complex scenario.

`type SubsetOfU<K extends Discriminator> = ??????`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript utility type over a discriminated union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111773/typescript-utility-type-over-a-discriminated-union-type)

Answer (score 14):

The `Extract` predefined type is already defined and does what you want:

```
type U = A | B | C;
type Discriminator = U["discriminator"];

type AorB = Extract<U, { discriminator: "A" | "B" }>;

const f = (d:AorB) => d.data;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QE2AGcEpgBbUOMAeygC5kAiVJgbhz32rkaLDIgA5hwC+WLKEixEKAEKZOuQiTKUQ1OoyZz2Sgjz4DQIrOMnho8JMgDCivAWKkKVWg2a29jkAFdyjH7kAEbQYhJgAJ4ADigAqsgAvGjIAD7ICum2HFGxyAAizmpudEnIcQDaTCou6ppQTAC6HFi5KKh0CskAogAeAohgADxxADSYTqquGu7arGnMusiiAHwtCDQg-MgwZQAU+PQdUHIAlEkrBAB03GBwbEA)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I already had code that did this so posting an answer I can find here when I forget about it again.

This is the solution:

```
type SubsetOfU<T, K> = T extends { discriminator: K }
  ? T
  : never;
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont actually need to use  `{ descriminator: 'A' | 'B'}` if you have defined types for subtypes, in your case `A`, `B` & `c`

```js
type U = A | B | C
type AorB = Extract<U, A | B>

const f = (d: AorB) => d.data
```