# Discriminated Union types cases from array

Tags: typescript

I can create a union type from a string a string array like this:

```
const types = [
  'AAA',
  'BBB'
] as const

type myType = typeof types[number]
```

`myType` now is `'AAA' | 'BBB'`

Now I want to create a discriminated union like this:

```
type typeAAA = {
  type: 'AAA'
  // further properties
}

type typeBBB = {
  type: 'BBB'
  // further properties
}

type typeAorB = typeAAA | typeBBB
```

I want to make sure, I can only use cases of `myType` for the discriminated union - is this possible?

**Update**:
I want to make sure the cases of `typeAorB` are in sync with the values of `types`. Right now I can assign an arbitrary string value to `type` of `typeAAA` or `typeBBB`

I don't want to use interfaces or classes.

I'm doing this because what I want is the ability to validate data and I want to validate `oneOf<myType>` (pseudo code) for `typeAorB`.

Comment: *"I want to make sure, I can only use cases of `myType` for the discriminated union..."* Can you clarify what you mean by that? It sounds like you're trying to prevent something, can you show an example of what you're trying to prevent?

Comment: I want to make sure the cases of `typeAorB` are in sync with the values of `types`. Right now I can assign whatever string value to `type` of `typeAAA` or `typeBBB`

Comment: So if, for example, you created a `typeCCC` with `type: "CCC"` but there was no `"CCC"` in `types`, you want to be prevented from including `typeCCC` in `typeAorB`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you essentially want to map over your union type to create a discriminated union, with the ability to attach custom properties to individual members of the union.

If that's indeed the case, you can use *distributive conditional types* to, well, distribute over your union type.

Something like

```js
const types = [
  'AAA',
  'BBB'
] as const

type myType = typeof types[number]

type Distribute<U> = U extends any
  ? U extends "AAA"
    ? { type: U, prop1: number }
    : U extends "BBB"
      ? { type: U, prop2: boolean }
      : never
  : never


type Discriminated = Distribute<myType>
```

This produces a union with this shape

```js
{
    type: "AAA";
    prop1: number;
} | {
    type: "BBB";
    prop2: boolean;
}
```

I'm assuming that the *further properties* of the union members need to be different, otherwise I don't think there's any point in having a discriminated union. Note that, because of this, if you add any new member to `myType` you have to handle it appropriately in `Distribute`.

Comment: **If** I'm understanding the end goal of the question correctly (big "if"), that doesn't prevent adding a `type: "CCC"` branch to the distribution if there's no `"CCC"` in `types` (though the type of `Discriminated` won't include that branch). [Example](https://tsplay.dev/NVKRMm) But at least, again, it doesn't show up in `Discriminated`.

Comment: (My almost-certainly-naive [solution](https://tsplay.dev/WolxLw) had the same problem.)

Comment: I see, I don't think I fully understood the question then. Hopefully OP can clarify

Comment: I don't know, your `Discriminated` looks a lot like the desired `typeAorB` to me, it would just be nice if we could get an error at the point of definition. It'll still give an error if you try to *use* that third type. That may be the best we can do.

Comment: Right. Ultimately it makes little difference where exactly the compiler spits out the error, as long as it stops you from doing something incorrect. You could argue that wanting `typeAorB to be in sync with the values of types` is not really what you want, what you really want is the compiler informing you when you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. The end goal was to prevent adding a `type: "CCC"`. But if it is not possible I think getting an error when trying to use `type: "CCC"` should be good enough. As @T.J.Crowder find this solution "cooler" I'll accept this one as answer. I find it more readable/approachable. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing I noticed right now: How could I do an `as` type assertion for `typeA` when using this approach?

Comment: This looks like a way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914158/90800

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler - *"As @ T.J.Crowder find this solution "cooler" I'll accept this one as answer."* Trust me, I'm not qualified to judge, still too new to TypeScript. :-) Glad this works and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get gives you an error if you try to *use* the third type, but no error where you add it to `typeAorB` ([bugs' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68844524/157247) has the same issue but is much cooler than the below). I wish I could get an error there.

I added a base type:

```typescript
type baseTypeAorB = {
    type: myType;
}
```

and included it in `typeAorB`:

```typescript
type typeAorB = baseTypeAorB & (typeAAA | typeBBB)
```

Now if you try to add a `typeCCC` to that, you (sadly) don't get an error:

```typescript
type typeCCC = {
  type: 'CCC'
  // further properties
}

type typeAorB = baseTypeAorB & (typeAAA | typeBBB | typeCCC) // No error (sadly)
```

but the resulting `typeAorB` **doesn't** have `typeCCC` in it; if you hover it in the playground, you see that it's still just:

```typescript
type typeAorB = (baseTypeAorB & typeAAA) | (baseTypeAorB & typeBBB)
```

`baseTypeAorB` basically blocks `typeCCC` from the type. As a result, you get an error if you try to use it as though it has `typeCCC` in it:

```typescript
let x: typeAorB = {
  type: "CCC" // <=== But there is an error here (yay!)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHAphGBeGBtAsAKBhgHIBBMogGn0KICF6j8BdGAQzVEigG598EUMALbwAKkmQY4EkADNpKCFjABXIQCNkAJya88-CTHXtk4lCRBbaUgN7VCC5AC5hYiXoC+fPAMm+yJLb2vi6k5PYA9BEwsipaUAAW2jCIWiAo8QCWqPhe+j6GvvTWmHYEjqHFjOVRMXGJyanp2lDZELnevo4Awr1B5SHEvd3VhLWx8UlaKWkZrTl4eQaC-pYlRiZmyBZWMABkMAAU-mQwAD6Oxec9vQCUMLUAciAw2mnThxCsACYANvC3by-ZCwAAeLlWu1KwQkLgARMM4Q9orQVLAGlpJABJADKbDAry07xgU0kmXk8BAKjgWngcBerGAUBUrF+-xgKggZPRCVYsAA7qx4LkgA)