# How can I reference to a type which is part of a union type, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I defined a union type for actions in TypeScript:

```
type Action = {
  type: 'reset',
} | {
  type: 'add',
  payload: number
} | {
  type: 'minus',
  payload: number
}
```

In some functions, I want to reference to a part of the union type, like:

```
function handleAdd(state: State, action: {
  type: 'add',
  payload: number
}): State => {
  // handle the add
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the typing of `action` so I don't need to repeat the full definition of

```
{
  type: 'add',
  payload: number
}
```

here?

Update:

I don't want to predefine each action type separately. Is there another solution, like `Action[type='add']`?

Comment: What is a problem to define unions parts as separate types or interfaces?

Comment: @НиколайГольцев Just want to explore more possibilities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript utility type over a discriminated union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111773/typescript-utility-type-over-a-discriminated-union-type)

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved relying on [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type ExtractType<T extends Action['type'], A = Action> =
    A extends { type: T } ? A : never;

type Add = ExtractType<'add'>; // { type: 'add'; payload: number; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AE4QDOEw5ANLgL5QA%20O%20hxEZ5AQwAmQptwJgBIADbJhZVAFcAtgCMIlVhy6Ei4PhWWIlNMbsky5QhSvWaWuXLygBRAB7BKAhABV9AHh8oCA8IVCEaWAQUVABtcl5yAF1GWEwopDQAPnSYYNDwyOw9UiggtgB%20NIUIADcNAG5HZxgRdPdPb2A-SH9BEXIshqgAehGcEoN%200WGLWXkoJTVGqBYgA)

> Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`

Answer (score 3):

create a type which narrows your union:

```
type TypedAction<T extends Action['type']> = Extract<Action, {type: T}>
```

and then use like:

```
(action: TypedAction<"add">)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQN4CgpSiQBcUA5AE4QDOEwZANLgL5QA%20O%20h4EpZAhgBNBjLmH4gANsiGlUAVwC2AIwgUW7TgSK9yixAuqiC4qTMFylq9c1y4dUACo9B8JGgA8jqBAAewCFRBalgEFFQAbTIdMgBdAD5MKABRfwp%20BA83cIYcHVJHZni7BxhhbLQk50hXMM8AIiFBevigA)

Comment: Be aware that when `type` is defined in the initial type as `type?`, then you have to add the `?` as well in the `Extract<>` bit.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor the branches of the Union out, so

```js
type Add = {
  type: 'add',
  payload: number
};
...
type Action = Add | ...;
...
```

Comment: This is one possible solution, I want to know if there is any other way not to pre-defined each type separately