# Dynamically use union type to define callback function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write the equivalent of a message subscription function. A simplified version without types looks like this:

```js
function newMessage(message) {
  postMessage(message)
}

function subscribe(messageType, callback) {
  handleNewMessage(message => {
    if (message.type === messageType) {
       callback(message.data)
    }
  })
}
```

`newMessage`'s `message` can be multiple types. Therefore I'm defining them separately, then using a discriminated union to type the `message` argument. An example:

```js
type FooMessage = {
  type: 'foo', 
  data: {
    a: string,
    b: number
  }
}

type BarMessage = {
  type: 'bar'
}

type MessageType = FooMessage | BarMessage
```

Note how `BarMessage` does not have any data associated.

This allows my `newMessage` function be typed like this:

```js
  function newMessage(message:MessageType):void {
    postMessage(message)
  }
```

I am not entirely sure how to type `subscribe` though. This is what I have so far:

```js
function subscribe(messageType: MessageType['type'], callback) {
  handleNewMessage(message => {
    if (message.type === messageType) {
       callback(message.data)
    }
  })
}
```

I am not entirely sure how to type `callback`. If I do `MessageType['data']` I get an error since `data` isn't always present. Even if I did define `data:undefined` on `BarMessage`, I have lost the link between the message type and the data.

Ideally, I would like to be able to write `subscribe('bar', (data) => console.log(data))` and typescript to know that `data` is actually undefined in this case.

One option I can see is to declare a function type multiple times for each message type I have, but this feels overly verbose since it means for each message type, I'm defining the `MessageType` and the associated subscribe function.

In reality, I have many many more messages and would prefer not to do this.

What is the best way to type `subscribe`'s `callback` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

- a generic type parameter `T` so that TypeScript can narrow the message type if it's statically known
- a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) with `Extract` which allows narrowing to a particular member type of a distributed union, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181463/how-can-i-reference-to-a-type-which-is-part-of-a-union-type-in-typescript) for more details
- a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to extract the type of `data` from a message only when its present as a key

```js
type TypedMessage<T extends MessageType['type']> = Extract<MessageType, { type: T }>;

type MessageData<M extends MessageType> = M extends { data: any } ? M['data'] : undefined;

function subscribe<T extends MessageType['type']>(
  messageType: T,
  callback: (data: MessageData<TypedMessage<T>>) => void
) {
  handleNewMessage(message => {
    if (message.type === messageType) {
       callback((message as { data?: any }).data)
    }
  })
}

subscribe('foo', (data) => console.log(data)); // typeof data === FooMessage['data']
subscribe('bar', (data) => console.log(data)); // typeof data === undefined
```

Here's a playground link [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I learnt a lot from this answer, thank you